# order of raphael.js animations

Tags: raphael

when changing size attributes of an image along with about 100 other rect elements, the image resize  happens last even though it is first element changed in my code.  Image change is made first within function A, all other changes are made within a loop in function B.   reference to elements stored in array 'shape'.   I

```
function A(){
   image.attr({'width':w, 'height':h});
   function B();
}

function B(){
  for(i=0;i>100;i+=1){
    shape[i].attr({'x':x, 'y':y});   
  }
```

}

Comment: I don't have an environment at the moment to test, but I'm guessing that modifying the width and height requires a page reflow while modifying the x and y values does not. Because of this I'm guessing the x and y changes are done immediately while Raphael waits to change the height and width until the next animation frame. You could test this by wrapping the call to `B()` in a `setTimeout` call.

Comment: 100% correct!  Wish i could give you an up vote. This answer will help me out in a couple different ways.  Thanks